# CSS div positioning and jQuery slideUp madness

Tags: jquery, html, css, slide

**SOLVED** Look at the comments below

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#playlistToggle').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        if($('#playlist').is(":hidden"))
        {
            $('#playlist').slideUp('medium');
        }

        else
        {
            $('#playlist').slideDown('medium');
        }

    });

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    #playlist_wrapper
    {
        bottom: 30px;
        height: 75px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: yellow;
    }

        #playlist
        {
            background-color: #FF6633;
            border: 1px solid #666666;
            height: 75px;
            width: 920px;
            position: relative;
            bottom: 0;
            margin: 0 auto;
            visibility: hidden;
        }
</style>

</head>

<a href="#" id="playlistToggle">Toggle Playlist</a>

<div id="playlist_wrapper">
    <div id="playlist"></div>
</div>
```

This script is supposed to slide up the playlist div when you hit the button. However, nothing happens when you hit it. If you change:

> if($('#playlist').is(":hidden"))

To:

> if($('#playlist').is(":visible"))

And change the css #playlist visibility property from "hidden" to "display", then the div slides up to the top, and slides down to the bottom, the exact opposite of what I want it to do. What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:** To clarify: I need the playlist div to be hidden from the start, and then slide up when I hit the toggle button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object is only conisdered hidden if

```
* They have a CSS display value of none.
* They are form elements with type="hidden".
* Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
* An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
```

It doesnt appear that `#playlist` meets any of those criteria so therefore the selector is not matching on the `#playlist`. Can you do away with the `.is(':hidden')` part and make due without it?

Comment: #playlist need to be hidden from the start and then slideUp from the bottom. I can't see any other way to hide the playlist from the start other than defining it in the css properties

Answer (score 1):

`.slideUp` is a synonym for `.hide`(albeit with different settings for how the effect is obtained)

likewise

`.slideDown` is a synonym for `.show`

all 4 are just preset animations.

If you read the jQuery documentation for slideUp and slideDown they go like this:

[slideUp:](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Description: Hide the matched elements with a sliding motion.

[slideDown:](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)

Description: Display the matched elements with a sliding motion.

Ergo: Use slideDown to make stuff visible and not slideUp

Comment: If I revert the functions in the 'if' statement, it stills doesn't do anything?

Comment: You cannot use slideDown (the show function) to make something slide up from the bottom of the screen, thats your problem. You have to rethink what you are doing.

Comment: I found a solution. Sliding the wrapper instead of the playlist instead worked.