# JQuery slide up and slide method executes after third click

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using the following Jquery function below to show and hide a map when a link is clicked, but the problem is that the link won't trigger until it is clicked for the third time.

I've tested it in all browsers so it's not a broswer issue...
Here is the javascript:

```
   $('#goo').live('click',function()  {
if ($('#map').is(':visible')){
  $('#map').slideUp('slow');  //or .toggle           
} else{
  $('#map').slideDown('slow'); //or .toggle   
  $("#map").css('visibility','inherit');
  $("#map").css('position','relative');
}
 return false;
```

});

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="wholeDiv">
<a href="#" id="goo"> Show Map </a>
<div id="map">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="testdiv"><img src="Kids_GiftGuide_SB.jpg" />
</div></div>
```

And I'll include the css too:

```
#map{
            position:absolute;
            width:450px;
            height:400px;
    visibility:hidden;
```

}

Comment: I think slide up and down only work with display:none; not visibility. It's working on the third click since you are setting the visibility in css then.

Comment: Is the problem that your handler isn't triggered until the third click, or that the slide up/down doesn't happen until the third click?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892743/css-div-positioning-and-jquery-slideup-madness for more info on :visible

Answer (score 0):

visibility:hidden is the issue

Change this to display: none, and it will work on the first click

You can also drop the `$("#map").css('visibility','inherit');`

Also, why is `position: relative` called the first time it is re-hidden? This is almost certainly also a mistake. If the position is to be relative, it probably should just start with that in the CSS code.

Comment: Thanks, using display:none did work but now when I click the link to show the map, half of the map is greyed out.
Any ideas why this is?

Comment: impossible to know from what you have above; can you provide a fiddle or example page? Also, that's technically a different question than what you asked ;)

Comment: Here is a url to the page: http://tasdesigns.ca/Gmap_example/index_hide1.html
The 'show map' link works fine now, it's just the rendering of the map that is the issue now.
If it's not one problem, it's another ;)

Comment: Okay, I know little about google map API, so take this for what it's worth. It looks to me like the map draws itself based on the size of the div it is contained in. To correctly calculate that, the div might need to be visible; you could test that by making it display: block initially and seeing if it has the same problem. Also, I think we're getting outside the scope of the original question at this point (maybe time for another one?)